# How to concatenate strings with TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How can I concatenate UTF-16 strings using `TMemoryStream`? I know `TStringBuilder` exists for such stuff but it has bad performance in multi-threaded scenarios and Eric Grange demonstrated that quite well on [his blog](http://www.delphitools.info/2013/10/30/efficient-string-building-in-delphi/). As shown on one of his fancy charts below.

[image: fancy chart]

Comment: What's wrong with using `TStringStream` instead?

Comment: @TLama By using TMemoryStream :)

Comment: @KenWhite Its worse than TStringBuilder?

Comment: Your code will probably be worse. Who says that string builder is your bottleneck? Eric's benchmark is artificial.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That doesn't change the fact that it performs bad in multithreaded scenarios.

Comment: I never said it did. But optimising something that is not a bottleneck is for sure a waste of time

Comment: @EricSantos - why were you thinking of using TStringBuilder in the first place? The idiomatic thing to do is naive string concatenation - Delphi's not Java or .NET.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston - for memory preallocation. Well, that still can be done using SetLength + Move instead of one-by-one concatenation

Comment: You have my downvote. When referring someone's research publication, please take a time to refer it directly, so we can review w/o resorting to web search. Apparently, Eric published a lot of benchmarks. See my edit.

Comment: @Arioch'The - the naive approach typically (easily) outperforms TStringBuilder even in that scenario, thanks to the memory manager. If however preallocation is found necessary, then indeed, I'd use SetLength (or SetString) like you rather than a class, let alone TStringBuilder specifically (which is entirely pointless).

Comment: @ChrisRolliston TStringBuilder is too high-level: it has a lot of virtual methods for dumping integers, objects, whatever. For a specific task "just copy them all" the low-tech approach would be better, of course. And - as the chart shows - avoiding of strings might be even faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate strings into a stream like this:

```
Stream.Write(Pointer(str1)^, Length(str1)*SizeOf(Char));
Stream.Write(Pointer(str2)^, Length(str2)*SizeOf(Char));
```

Some comments:

1. You'll likely need to use a more customised stream than TMemoryStream.
2. The string builder code may not be your bottleneck. And Eric's benchmark was by necessity artificial.
3. Using a better memory manager may improve performance much more than rolling your own string builder.

Comment: One question at a time please. You asked about concatenating strings into streams.

Comment: And we are at the beginning again. That `TBinaryWriter` does internally the same as `TStringStream` when calling `WriteString`. It takes internally stored `TEncoding` class instance and get bytes from it. And those bytes it writes to the stream. Code in this post is the lowest way you can go with RTL classes to write a string into the memory stream. Why do you still want that sugar around ?

Comment: @TLama Good point. Didn't know TBinaryWriter uses TStringStream.

Comment: I didn't said that. The `TStringStream` uses the same mechanism as `TBinaryWriter` uses for writing chars. Your yesterday's question used a memory stream into which you were writing through `TBinaryWriter`. I've suggested you to use `TStringStream` instead, because `TStringStream` is directly intended for string streams. Today you are asking how to write a string into a memory stream and yet again you're asking for using `TBinaryWriter`. Why ? Forget on that `TBinaryWriter`. The lowest RTL level for what you have asked now is code in this post. With it you don't need `TBinaryWriter` anymore.

Comment: I've no idea? Do you? The code in the question doesn't write #0 characters, unless the string has some inline.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there a custom memorystream that avoids fragmentation?

Comment: I have one of my own. What is your underlying problem. I do wonder whether your diagnosis is accurate. Have you timed your existing code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I ended up using THeapMemoryStream from SynCommons.pas :)